# drawer navigator - add a screen without displaying in the drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I wanna be able to add `Drawer.Screen` inside `NavigationContainer` but don't want to display on the drawer.

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Search">
      <Drawer.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="DetailScreen" component={DetailScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
```

I don't want to display `DetailScreen` in the drawer, but want to keep it so that I can navigate to this screen inside my components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: if you are using React navigation 5 (which seem to be the case)

- you will be needed to install stack navigator; make sure you have it
- import it in your main container file using

  import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

then just do this

```
 <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="DetailScreen"
      component={DetailScreen}
    />
   // add the whole drawer as a stack screen and you shall have what you want
    <Stack.Screen
      name="drawer"
      component={DrawerNavigation}
      headerShown={false}
      options={{headerMode: 'none', headerShown: false}}
    />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

then you have to create another file for having the drawer navigation in it like:

DrawerNavigation.js  and export it to be used in your main navigator like in the pic below

```
<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Search">
  <Drawer.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="DetailScreen" component={DetailScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

[image]

> Here **SceneNavigator** is the main navigator.

**sample screen for drawer navigator code being exported as component**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Dimensions, Platform} from 'react-native';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import Home from '../scenes/Home';
import SideMenu from './SideMenu';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const AppDrawerNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="home"
      // this is for custom design for drawer
      drawerContent={(props) => <SideMenu {...props} />}
      drawerType="slide"
      edgeWidth={250}
      hideStatusBar={Platform.OS === 'android' ? true : false}
      drawerPosition="left"
      drawerStyle={{
        width:
          Dimensions.get('window').width - Dimensions.get('window').width / 5,
      }}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
export default AppDrawerNavigator;
```

Comment: This is invalid component code. Check your answer thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is create a stack navigator, and then nest the stack navigator as one of your drawer screens or both your drawer screens depending on your use case, that way you can navigate into the screen but won't display it in the drawer. For example,

```
const NotificationsAndDetails = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="DetailScreen" component={DetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

<NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Search">
      <Drawer.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="NotificationsAndDetails" component={NotificationsAndDetails} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

More about nesting navigators here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/